# Using QT Jambi to make screenshots

Tags: java, screenshot, qt-jambi

I am using QT Jambi (java) to make screenshots of a browser window.
My main method starts the framework like this:

```
QApplication.initialize(new String[1]);

ScreenshotMain widget = new ScreenshotMain();
widget.showFullScreen();
QApplication.exec();
```

and when the browser is done with the loading the following method is invoked and takes the screenshot.

```
public void loadDone() {
// Taking screenshot
QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap = QPixmap.grabWidget(browser);

pixmap.save(writeTo, "png");
System.out.println("Made screenshot "+writeTo);

browser.loadProgress.disconnect(this);
browser.loadFinished.disconnect(this);
QApplication.closeAllWindows();
```

}

My question now is the following:

How can I make screenshots out of an application without having to open a browser window, have it load the content. The idea is that I have a server application and I don´t want to open a window to make the screenshot.

Does anyone of you have experience to make screenshots using QT Jambi in this way.

Thanks a lot for your help
Marc

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for: [linky](http://hoheinzollern.wordpress.com/2009/03/21/off-screen-rendering-with-qtjambi-jogl/)